# Find where in an html file there is text using python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I need to modify the text (what is seen on a browser) in an HTML file. The result should be the same html code except for the text elements, which should be enclosed between   tags. Note that I do not know a priori what text I will find, just that this text is what will be shown in the browser.

I have found many answers proposing python html-to-text scripts, but none gives me the locations of such text elements and I feel it should be simpler and more efficient to directly get these locations, instead of doing a search or each returned text string.

Comment: What you are looking for is templating. There are many templating engines for python to create html-files. Look at [Templating](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for your comment, although I do not know exactly what you mean. I looked into templating in python, but it looks like it will only help me if I know a priori what is the text I want to replace. Could you be more specific?

Comment: How can you replace a text, without knowing the text? can you give an example?

Comment: Give some example - what do you want to do step by step - because I (only) guess you need `web scraping+replacing` - getting existing page from internet, getting some text from that page, replacing that text with new text and saving result on local computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding you're trying to parse HTML, find all texts, enclose them in some kind of element.

You can do this using html5lib:

```
import html5lib
from html5lib import treebuilders


parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"))
root = parser.parse(some_html)
help(root)
```

When you have your parsed HTML you will be able to iterate each elements, check if they contains text or match your criteria, modify them, and rebuild the document. From this point, read the documentation of lxml.